# Return NotMapped property in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have one entity which is used in Entity Framework Code First.

```
 public class MyEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> ListOfValues
        {
            get
            {
                return StringsAsStrings?.Split(';').ToList();
            }
            set
            {
                StringsAsStrings = value.Count > 0 ? String.Join(";", value) : null;
            }
        }
        [Column("ListOfValues")]        
        private string StringsAsStrings { get; set; }
        public int RelationId { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am giving values as List to public and that should be stored as semicolon(;) separated string as in the table.

As this is specific to this data model, I specified *StringsAsStrings* as *private* and created a *Convention* to include in the migraion. All these are fine.

Now my scenario is to select the collection using *LINQ*. Please check the following linq query i used;

```
var items = from A in MyContext.MyEntities.Where(x => x.RelationId == paramId)
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = A.Id,
                            Name = A.Name,
                            ListOfValues = A.ListOfValues,
                        };
            var result = items.ToList();
```

Here I got following error

> The specified type member '*ListOfValues*' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Ok fine. EF didn't support NotMapped properties. So for the work around i just changed private StringsAsStrings to *public* *StringsAsStrings*. Then changed the linq like below;

```
var items = from A in MyContext.MyEntities.Where(x => x.RelationId== paramId)
                select new
                {
                    Id = A.Id,
                    Name = A.Name,
                    ListOfValues = A.StringsAsStrings.Split(';').ToList(),
                };
    var s = items.ToList();
```

Now i got the following error;

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[]
>   Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Please help to solve this case. 
Also help me if any other work around for this to avoid changing *private* to *public* property.

Comment: Linq is not able to translate `Sting.Split` to respective SQL operation. That's why you are seeing this error. `var items = from A in MyContext.MyEntities.Where(x => x.RelationId== paramId).ToList()` should resolve the issue. You don't need to use `select` because `ListOfValue` no need to populate explictily.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hi i got your point. But i can't simply use ToList(). I need to use left outer join with other entity and need to get the values

Comment: If you have to do join then don't use ToList() but you also should not use select. Are you doing JOIN on the ListOfValues property ?

Comment: No. i need to join with entity and then select properties from both tables. Yes currently i just removed ToList() method inside select and its ok for now